# Renaming PDF File with Apple Script

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to rename a finder item called "Invoice Template.pdf" when it is added to my folder with Automator. However, every time the script runs, I get Finder got an error: Can’t set file "Invoice Template.pdf" to "Invoice 11.08.2021.pdf". Any ideas why?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set dateObj to (current date)
    set theMonth to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & (month of dateObj as number))
    set theDay to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & day of dateObj)
    set theYear to year of dateObj
    set dateStamp to "" & theMonth & "." & theDay & "." & theYear
    set theFile to "DBF Invoice Template.pdf"
    set theName to "Invoice"
    set the name of file theFile to theName & " " & dateStamp & ".pdf"
    
end tell
```

Comment: You should assign to theFile variable full HFS path of your pdf.

Comment: In your question you mention **Automator**. What does **Automator** have to do with this? When you say '"Invoice Template.pdf" when it is added to my folder with Automator' is this a **Folder Action** scenario you created in **Automator**?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes. My apologies that I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set dateObj to (current date)
set theMonth to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & (month of dateObj as number))
set theDay to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & day of dateObj)
set theYear to year of dateObj
set dateStamp to "" & theMonth & "." & theDay & "." & theYear

set theFileHFS to (choose file of type "com.adobe.pdf") as text
set theName to "Invoice"

tell application "Finder"
    set the name of file theFileHFS to theName & " " & dateStamp & ".pdf"
end tell
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the full HFS path of my specific PDF file? It is always in the same spot. But when I try the path "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Dropbox/Invoices/Invoice Template.pdf" it does not work.

Comment: "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Dropbox/Invoices/Invoice Template.pdf" is not HFS path, but POSIX path. If you can see and select  your pdf in the Finder, you can get as well its correct HFS path runninng script **set theFileHFS to (choose file of type "com.adobe.pdf") as text** and choosing your pdf

Comment: Finder doesn’t understand POSIX paths, only colon-delimited HFS paths (which are obsolete and have issues with volume names). You can use System Events, which does understand POSIX paths, or you can coerce the POSIX path string to a POSIX file value and give that to Finder.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Sorry about that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Finder where the file is:

```
property myFolder: "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Dropbox/Invoices" as POSIX file

tell application "Finder"
    ...
    set theFile to "DBF Invoice Template.pdf"
    set theName to "Invoice"
    set the name of file theFile of folder myFolder to theName & " " & dateStamp & ".pdf"
    
end tell
```